# neo4j- Cypher help in Applications Dependencies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement for an output :

1. There are 50 Apps
2. Some of the apps are inter depended
3. The relation can be bidirectional. Or the relation type between 2 apps can be "Inbound" or "outbound".
4. the output needs to show a graph for these 50 apps showing the dependencies (inbound/outbound).
5. The MyApplication database for 50 apps have the fields:- S.No, App Id, App Name, Relation (inbound/outbound), TargetApp.

I have loaded the data from CSV to Neo4j. 
I am now trying to create a relation amongst the apps (for in/out)

```
MATCH (fromApp:MyApps),(toApp:MyApps)
WHERE fromApp.Relation="Inbound" and fromApp.TargetAppId=toApp.AppId
CREATE (fromApp)-[r:inbound]->(toApp)
RETURN fromApp,toApp
```

To keep it simple I created only the inbound relationship first

The resulted graph shows the redundancy. This is probably the consequence of Cartesian Product as a result of the MATCH
Can anyone suggest how to correct the above relation to display the correct set of apps with correct relationship?

1) Does it need any constraints in Cypher?

2) What is the correct cipher query for the relation?

3)Do I need to do anything during the loading of the data from csv to neo4j? (It is just one table)

Table Structure:

```
SNo,AppId,AppName,Relation,TargetAppId
1,101,Azak,Inbound,102
2,101,Azak,Outbound,102
3,102,Trophy,,Outbound,101
4,103,Elan,Inbound,101
5,104,Abaan,Inbound,101
6,105,DLM,Outbound,101
7,106,WhiteCar,Outbound,105
8,107,Jewel,Outbound,105
9,108,Lexin,Outbound,101
```

Comment: Apologies for the Title mismatch. However, the solution will be still valid for Employee/Manager problem statement in neo4j.

Comment: I see many have visited this post. Can someone post a reply here?